# How to write a select between two letters in Oracle database?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I am writing a PL/SQL script where I get two letters from the user, let's call them letter1 and letter2. I need to be able select all customers in the database whose names start with the letters between letter1 and letter2 (inclusive). This is what I have so far:

```
ACCEPT p_fletter PROMPT 'First letter: '
ACCEPT p_lletter PROMPT 'Last letter: '
DECLARE
    CURSOR allCusts IS
        SELECT name
          FROM customer
         WHERE name ... -- stuck here
BEGIN
    -- call the above in some loop
END;
/
```

How can I select a value that starts with a letter in the range between p_fletter and p_lletter? I am using Oracle database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be

```
WHERE substr(name,1,1) between p_fletter and p_lletter
```

`substr(name,1,1)` will return the first character of `name`.  Then you can use standard `between` logic.

Since you're applying a function on `name`, be aware that this query can't use a standard index on `name`.  If that is important, you could create a function-based index on `substr(name,1,1)`.  As written, this query is also case-sensitive ("B" is between "A" and "C" but not between "a" and "c").  You may want to use the `upper` or `lower` function to all three letters in order to do a case-insensitive comparison.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by standard index. In regards to the casing issue, I was considering using the UPPER function, so the code above could be something like `WHERE  SUBSTR(UPPER(name),1,1) BETWEEN UPPER(p_fletter) AND UPPER (p_lletter)` Is there any issues in doing something like this?

Comment: @user4181107 - Yes, if you want to do a case-insensitive comparison, using `upper` like you're doing here would work.  By "standard index" I mean a b*tree index created on `name`, the sort of index that you'd get by default when you did something like `create index <<index name>> on table_name( name )`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ACCEPT p_fletter PROMPT 'First letter: '
ACCEPT p_lletter PROMPT 'Last letter: '
DECLARE
CURSOR allCusts IS
    SELECT name
      FROM customer
     WHERE name like "'||p_fletter||'%'||'p_lletter'"
BEGIN
-- call the above in some loop
END;
```

Comment: Can you add some text to explain how your answer solves the OP's problem?

Comment: @BSL Technologies, I see what you were doing there but I think by "first letter" and "last letter" the OP wants to find customers where their name falls lexicographically between the two letters, e.g. "A" to "M" would return ADAM, BILL, and MAX but not NELLY or ZACK.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ordinary index on `name` you could use the following to maximise the chances that an index range scan will be used:

```
WHERE name BETWEEN p_fletter AND p_lletter || CHR(127)
```

However, this doesn't help if you want case-insensitive matching, in which case you would be better off using Justin's suggestion with the FBI.